# Adding to someone else’s pull request on a GitHub project that I do not own

Tags: git, github

Is it possible for me to add commits to *someone else’s* pull request on a repository where I am not the owner?

e.g.

User A owns Project X.

User B forks Project X, creates a feature branch, makes some changes, and submits a pull request.

User C likes the pull request, but would like to make some modifications to it. (FWIW User C already has a fork of Project X, so is unable to easily fork User B’s fork).

Can User C add commits to User B’s PR?

Comment: Maybe user C can create a PR to merge their changes into User B's feature branch?  I.e. in `https://github.com/userb/satpy/pulls`?  Comment rather than answer because I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot add commits directly to User B's pull-request unless you have write access to User B's fork. You can, however, make local additions to the pull-request, by just fetching the pull-request branch into your own local repo (assuming the url for B's fork is public).

I'm not sure if it's possible to do a pull-request into B's fork since your own fork is from A and not B, though.

Comment: This is not adding commits to user Bs PR, but adding commits to a local copy.

Answer (score 47):

You can check out the branch and re-submit a modified PR (giving credit to the original, preferably).

You can also issue a PR to the PR author:

```
git remote add userb https://github.com/userb/name.git
git fetch userb
git checkout featurebranch
[change and commit]
git push userc featurebranch
```

When you create a PR, GitHub lets you choose the base branch - so you can choose the fork and - if you want to - request changes to the PR.

Comment: So I (user C) can create another PR2 with changes to the branch user B has, so that when he merges that PR2, the commits automatically appear in user Bs PR1.

Comment: This worked for me, yes. However, it can maybe get complicated if a) you want a clean history; b) having merged your changes, user B finds that his PR1 still doesn't work. PR2 is merged & closed, so not editable at this point if you adjust again and force push. You can just issue PR3 against his branch, but I don't think you can tidy up the prior history and hide the flaw in PR2. If you don't mind having a bunch of WIP commits then it should still work (although maybe the original owner does mind - in that case user B could clean it up before acceptance).

Comment: I applied the technique and it worked for me. The commits I (user C) did ended up in the PR of user B.


I understand the tricky aspects you describe.

Answer (score 9):

User C can add directly to User B's pull request if User B has given permission, or possibly if user C is a committer on User A's repo.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork

The github default permissions for users on a fork are copied from the original.

If you do have permissions your command line to add would look like this:

`git push https://github.com/[userb]/[projectx].git [userc_localbranch]`

Answer (score 1):

With the [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/) this has become rather easy.

```sh
gh repo clone userb/repo
git checkout featurebranch

# make some changes and commit

gh pr create --base featurebranch

# follow instructions
```

It will automatically create a fork for your user, push the changes to it and open a pull request to the repo of User B. Once User B merges the changes, they will appear in the original PR.