# Can I modify someone else's pull request and push it back in its branch?

Tags: github, pull-request

GitHub explains you can fork, modify, commit, push and trigger a pull request. They also explain that you can still modify, commit, push and the request is updated on the website.

I would like to know if it is possible to do the exact same thing but not being the author of the fork? I am the owner of a repo with pull requests I would like to correct myself but still discuss afterwards... I was trying to push my changes into the author's repo (thinking some right access would be calculated) but the access is denied.

Comment: Pull the branch, modify, and push? But if you don't have access to their repo, of course not.

Comment: Make your changes. Send him a message to sync his fork.

Comment: That's why I am asking. This process (of collaborating with unknown people) seems so natural to me that I am surprised it is not (easily) supported.

Comment: Related: [Adding to someone else’s pull request on a GitHub project that I do not own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237609/adding-to-someone-else-s-pull-request-on-a-github-project-that-i-do-not-own)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating a pull request (PR) on GitHub, you can select the option that maintainers are allowed to commit changes to your PR. You can also do this after the PR is already created: In the detail view of the PR, on the lower right, under "Unsubscribe", "participants". So if *you* want to commit to a PR of someone else on a GitHub repository you own: Ask them to give you this permission.

[image]

From the GitHub help pages: *"Only pull request creators can give upstream repository maintainers, or those with push access to the upstream repository, permission to make commits to their pull request's compare branch."* ([Allowing changes to a pull request branch created from a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/))

Unfortunately, as far as I know, in order for someone to commit to the PR, you would have to give them write access to the repository and can't just selectively give them write access to the PR.

Comment: @SybillePeters-onstrike Your answer here seems to be what I would like to do. However, as an owner I don't seem to get access, see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58614181/2646505). Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Tom I think your problem may be unrelated to the question of having permission to push to author or PR repo (as owner). It may be a question of authenticating in general. I will answer in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Official GitHub support answer at this date

> It would be up to the owner of the forked repository to decide if they
>   want to pull your changes into their fork.
>
> You would modify their Pull Request and merge it into your repository.
>   You could then request them to pull down the changes you have made
>   into his fork which would synch his fork with yours.

Comment: to me this is incorrect UX. i mean i understand why. there needs to be a more automated way for people clearly working together to skip this step and let the original maintainer be able to push to the PR without requesting access. there should at least be like a button for the PR contributor to press right within the PR. a checkbox to allow anyone with access to the parent repo to contribute to the PR.

Comment: @facyspacey.com You were looking for "a checkbox to allow anyone with access to the parent repo to contribute to the PR." Well now [you can](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/). It looks like it defaults to allowing edits.