# Amend pull request from another-one's fork

Tags: git, github

Another user submitted a pull request on my repository (e.g. `myself/foorbar`), by:

1. Creating a fork (e.g. `otheruser/foobar`).
2. Committing to a branch on her/his fork (e.g. `otheruser/foobar:patch`).
3. Opening a pull request on Github, enabling, "Allow edits from maintainers".

Now I wish to amend this pull request. Following [Github's reader](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork), I:

1. Cloned the fork:

   ```sh
   cd forks
   git clone https://github.com/otheruser/foobar.git
   ```
2. Checked out the branch used to open the pull request:

   ```sh
   cd foobar
   git checkout patch
   ```
3. Committed to the branch.

   ```sh
   ...
   git add -A
   git commit -m "Amendments"
   ```

Now I wish to push the changes:

```sh
git push origin patch
```

But Github prompts me for my username and password and then responds:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/otheruser/foobar.git/'
```

So my question: **How do I use my right as a maintainer/owner to edit the pull request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You steps sound correct.

Have you checked if the permission problem is really related to pushing to the other's repo? Your error message does sound like it may be related to wrong username / password.

- If you use the same procedure to push to your repo - does it work?
- Do you usually use `http://` repo URL and username / password? Have you tried switching to SSH key procedure with `git@` ... URL (You can switch when you use the clone or download button on GitHub). This has the additional advantage that it gives you a smoother workflow using your ssh key: You do not have to enter username / password all the time, you can protect SSH key with passphrase and enter passphrase once per session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It work with the SSH key. What is strange that I'm sure that my credentials are right. I rechecked many times, also verifying Github's login

Comment: Besides, Github's manual seems to suggest to specifically use the `https` API? I would say that in all cases the SSH API is more favourable?

Comment: @Tom I guess, it should work with both: user /password or ssh key (but I must admit I always use ssh). I mostly suggested using ssh to eliminate some possible problems with wrong credentials or other. Once we get one part working, we can narrow down the problem more easily. But, I agree in the long run, ssh is the better choice anyway.

Comment: I think I may know why the https authentication failed: I am used two-factor authentications, and I used my password and and not an access token. Anyway, thanks once again! From now on I will only the the SSH authentication also in to this case.